# What's the correct way to author a NuGet package that must add references to older framework assemblies?

Tags: nuget, nuspec

I'm trying to author a NuGet package that can be added into a .net 4.0 or 4.5 project. The actual assemblies contained in the package are all built against .net 3.5, all except one which is built against .net 4.0 - I have no control over this so I have to use the assemblies 'as is'.

The project I'm working on targets .net 4.5.2 and needs to have these 'legacy' assemblies referenced. I have enabled 'legacy runtime activation' by having the following in my App.config:

```
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2"/>
  </startup>
```

This all seems to work well enough. Now, I wish to package my 'legacy' assemblies into a NuGet package. My .nuspec file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/08/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <!-- many lines elided for clarity -->
        <references>
            <group>
                <reference file="NetFx35Assembly1.dll" />
                <reference file="NetFx35Assembly2.dll" />
            </group>
            <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.5.2" >
                <reference file="NetFx40Assembly.dll" />
            </group>
         </references>
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <!-- .net 3.5 assemblies -->
        <file src="NetFx35Assembly1.dll" target="lib\net35\NetFx35Assembly1.dll" />
        <file src="NetFx35Assembly2.dll" target="lib\net35\NetFx35Assembly2.dll" />
        <!-- .net 4.0 assemblies -->        
        <file src="NetFx40Assembly.dll" target="lib\net40\NetFx40Assembly.dll" />
    </files>
</package>
```

My expectation was that when I added this package to my .net 4.5.2 project, it would do the following:

1. Reference the 3.5 assemblies, because they are in a 'default' group that doesn't specify any framework
2. Reference the 4.0 assembly, because it is specified in a group that targets 4.5.2

Things did not work out as I expected. What I actually got was a single reference to the 4.0 assembly.

What is the correct way to author the behaviour that I want? How can I make the NuGet package ensure that the `<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">` tag is present in the App.config file?

Answer (score 1):

For groups of references NuGet will install all items for one group only. It does not install the group without any framework specified if there is a more specific match. This default group is used if there are no other matches for the project's target framework.

Also I would probably not explicitly target .NET 4.5.2 in the NuGet package unless the .NET 4.0 assemblies target .NET 4.5.2 only. If they are compatible with .NET 4.0 I would have them target .NET 4.0

```
        <group targetFramework="net35">
            <reference file="NetFx35Assembly1.dll" />
            <reference file="NetFx35Assembly2.dll" />
        </group>
        <group targetFramework="net40" >
            <reference file="NetFx35Assembly1.dll" />
            <reference file="NetFx35Assembly2.dll" />
            <reference file="NetFx40Assembly.dll" />
        </group>
```

Note the above is equivalent to not having the references defined in the metadata section and just using:

```
<files>
    <!-- .net 3.5 assemblies -->
    <file src="NetFx35Assembly1.dll" target="lib\net35" />
    <file src="NetFx35Assembly2.dll" target="lib\net35" />
    <!-- .net 4.0 assemblies -->        
    <file src="NetFx35Assembly1.dll" target="lib\net40" />
    <file src="NetFx35Assembly2.dll" target="lib\net40" />
    <file src="NetFx40Assembly.dll" target="lib\net40" />
</files>
```

For the app.config file I would look at using an [XML document transform](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/configuration-file-and-source-code-transformations) to add the startup element.